# help creating a shell script

Tags: shell-script

I'm not a deep shell script connoisseur, I know the basics and I'm open to suggestions for my problem,
I need to put together a script that runs 24 hours a day, but honestly I don't even know where to start,
any idea how to assemble this script according to the case below?

I have the following scenario, EXAMPLE 1 (this is how it is today) and EXAMPLE 2 (expected result)

EXAMPLE 1

```
#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.006813
change: +1.6%
Count Number: 1

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.006969
change: +2.3%
Count Number: 2

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007060
change: +1.3%
Count Number: 3

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007300
change: +3.4%
Count Number: 4

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007453
change: +2.1%
Count Number: 5
```

EXAMPLE 2

```
#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.006813
change: +1.6%
Count Number: 1

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.006969
change: +3.9%
Count Number: 2

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007060
change: +5.2%
Count Number: 3

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007300
change: +8.6%
Count Number: 4

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007453
change: +10.7%
Count Number: 5
```

Requirements:

1- The item #Price_Notification_ProductABC is not a fixed item, the search can return several products (Price_Notification_ProductABC, #Price_Notification_ProductXYZ, #Price_Notification_Product123, etc) so, for this to work correctly, I believe it is necessary to have a match using grep that matches the first notification received for this item

2- The Price item does not have pre-defined decimal places, it can be in the format Price: 0.006813 Price: 1.256 Price: 524.354, etc, it is something dynamic

3- The change item is the most complex to explain, the notifications return with the percentage containing numbers always fractional as in EXAMPLE 1,

- I would like to have a filter that does the sum of the calculation incrementally as in EXAMPLE 2
- this incremental sum must always add the percentage of the previous notification + the percentage of the current notification
- but it is necessary to have some conditions for this:
  The Price item of the current notification must always have a value greater than that of the previous notification, if this condition is not met,
  the cycle/filter containing the sum/percentage of notifications must be reset, thus starting a new cycle for subsequent notifications

4- The Count Number item, I don't really know how to handle this item, as the Count Number is also dynamic and is always reset to 0 every hour, but I'm open to suggestions on how to handle this item

---

Note, I get this information that way, there's not much I can do about it, I'm trying to build a script that serves me according to the information received.

There are two more criteria/conditions that I need to resolve, when one of these two conditions exists, the incremental/increasing percentage calculation must be reset, starting a new cycle

1- The percentage needs to be calculated incrementally/increasingly, within a window of 0 to a maximum of 30 minutes between one notification and another, from minute 31, the incremental calculation of the percentage needs to be reset/restarted, starting a new one calculation cycle

2- The last notification received from the Price item cannot contain a value lower than the previous notification, for example, I received three more new notifications (Count Number: 6, Count Number: 7 and Count Number: 8)

```
#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007023
change: +1.8%
Count Number: 6

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007184
change: +2.3%
Count Number: 7

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007328
change: +3.3%
Count Number: 8
```

In this example, as the item `Price: 0.007023` of the notification Count Number: 6 has a lower value than the item `Price: 0.007453` of the previous notification Count Number: 5, I need a new cycle to be started, zeroing/restarting all calculations done previously.

It should look like this:

```
#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007023
change: +1.80%
Count Number: 6

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007184
change: +4.10%
Count Number: 7

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007328
change: +7.40%
Count Number: 8
```

Any suggestions to solve this other condition?

Thanks!

Comment: in your output, what determines if you output `change` or `1 min change`?

Comment: `The item #Price_Notification_ProductABC is not a fixed item` it seems to be based on your input. `The Price item` is numeric, right? `The Price item of the current notification must always have a value greater than that of the previous notification` it seems to be the case in your input. `the Count Number is also dynamic and is always reset to 0 every hour` your example data doesn't reflect that

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the data provided, the correct one is change and not 1 min change

Yes, price is numeric, about the Count Number item I believe it will not be a mandatory item, maybe I can manipulate this part and exclude it from the final result, thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not use a CSV-format (and include a timestamp) for this? That way calulations, graphics and all would be much simpler to handle.

Comment: `grep` is out of place here: (a) you cannot search for an item you have not seen yet; (b) as your products can be mixed, you need to retain data for all those already seen. Awk  is good for this kind of problem (use plain shell only if performance is not an issue).

Comment: @FelixJN I have no restrictions to use CSV format or any other alternative, I just need it to run on linux, now how it will run is indifferent to me, I just need it to work... Any suggestions where should I start? Thanks

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I thought of something related to shell script because that's where I have a little more familiarity, however any solution adopted will be difficult because I would like to learn how to do it myself, I know that my case is very complex and I understand that it will be very difficult to get answers for everyone my queries. What I'm really looking for is just a direction to start assembling this script, because I know what I want, but I don't know how to build it, I'm humbly open to suggestions and any help that at least shows me the path to follow, I need to have a start. Thanks

Comment: `sed 's/^.*: //'  INPUTFILE | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n" ; OFS=","} {$1=$1} 1'` ... now this will transform your data (as you provided) into a CSV. With now all in columns, you may use `akw` - number formatting is not a problem and you may do your calculations as wished. However, you sure want to keep in mind that +2%, then +3% does not equal +5%.

Comment: @FelixJN I run the mentioned script: `sed 's/^.*: //'  /opt/scripts/input | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n" ; OFS=","} {$1=$1} 1'`, it printed the following information on the screen: `,52.1%453otification_ProductABC`
Any ideas on how to improve the result, and a second question, any way to make the sum of +2% and +3% = +5% ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as difficult as it seems, it's fairly easy to do in either `awk` or `perl`.

Using perl:

```
$ perl -lpe 'if (/^#Price_Notification_Product/) {
               $prod = $_;
             } elsif (/^change: ([^%]*)%/) {
               $products{$prod} += $1;
               $_ = "change: +$products{$prod}%";
             }' input.txt 
#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.006813
change: +1.6%
Count Number: 1

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.006969
change: +3.9%
Count Number: 2

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007060
change: +5.2%
Count Number: 3

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007300
change: +8.6%
Count Number: 4

#Price_Notification_ProductABC
Price: 0.007453
change: +10.7%
Count Number: 5
```

- perl's `-l` option turns on automatic handling of line-endings (e.g. strip newlines from input, add them to output by `print` statements)
- the `-p` option makes it work like sed (i.e. read each input line and print it automatically after any processing)
- `-e` tells perl that the next arg is a script to be executed.

The script reads each input line and if the line starts with "#Price_Notification_Product" stores the current line in variable `$prod`.

Otherwise, if the line starts with "change: ", it:

- extracts the value of the change using regex capture, and adds the value to a hash (AKA "associative array") called `%products`.  The key to the hash is the product name (`$prod`).

  It uses a hash so that it can handle any number of product names in the input - as long as the `#Price_Notification_Product...` lines are unique and consistent for each product. Each product name's cumulative total will be tracked independently.
- changes the current line (variable `$_`) so that it has the current cumulative total for that product.

  BTW, if you want the "change: " line to have a fixed number of digits before and/or after the decimal point, you can use `sprintf`.  e.g. change the `$_ = "change...."` line to:

  ```
             $_ = sprintf("change: %7.2f%%", $products{$prod});
             s/(\d)/+$1/;
  ```

  Which would output "change" lines looking like this:

  ```
  change:   +1.60%
  change:   +3.90%
  change:   +5.20%
  change:   +8.60%
  change:  +10.70%
  ```

All input lines are printed, whether they have been modified or not.

Input can come from a file (e.g. `input.txt` as I have used) or from stdin (e.g. a pipe from `tail -f`).

---

BTW, it just occurred to me that you might want the cumulative total for a product to be reset to zero when its count is reset to zero.  If that's the case, change the last line from this:

```
         }' input.txt
```

to this:

```
         } elsif (/^Count Number: 0$/) {
           $products{$prod} = 0;
         }' input.txt
```

---

Same thing as a standalone script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -lp

if (/^#Price_Notification_Product/) {
  $prod = $_;
} elsif (/^change: ([^%]*)%/) {
  $products{$prod} += $1;
  $_ = "change: +$products{$prod}%";
}
```

If your perl interpreter is in a different location, you'll need to adjust `#!` line to refer to the correct full path.

Save it as, e.g., `./script.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x script.pl`, and run it like:

```
$ ./script.pl input.txt
```

or

```
$ perl -lp ./script.pl input.txt
```

---

awk version, a direct translation of the perl version but we also have to use `gsub()` to remove the `+` and `%` symbols from the second field of each "change:" line:

```c
$ awk '
/^#Price_Notification_Product/ {
  prod = $0;
}
/^change: / {
  gsub(/[+%]/,"",$2);
  products[prod] += $2;
  $2 = "+" products[prod] "%"
}
1' input.txt
```

The `1` on the last line of the awk script is not a typo - that's what tells awk to always print the current line whether it has been modified or not (awk scripts are essentially a series of PATTERN ACTION rules, if the PATTERN evaluates as true then the ACTION is executed.  `1` evaluates as true, and the default action is `{print}`)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help, I copied it exactly as it is to a file renamed to script.pl, I executed the script through the command `perl script.pl`, 
but it returned the following message of `"error: syntax error at script.pl line 6, near "}'" Execution of script.pl aborted due to compilation errors."` Any idea what it could

Comment: And if possible, could you show me an example of how this script would look using awk instead of perl?

Comment: if you copied it exactly as is into a script then it won't work.  That's a perl one-liner meant to be run as a command in your shell.  To convert to standalone script, just copy everything inside the single-quotes and nothing else. Then add `#!/usr/bin/perl -lp` as the **first** line of the script (you may need to adjust this if your perl is in a different directory), and make it executable with `chmod +x script.pl`.  You can then execute it with `./script.pl` OR `perl -lp script.pl`.  The `-l` and `-p` options are essential for this script to work.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to run the scripts both in perl and awk, now I have two more conditions that I need to solve (I edited the initial post and put the details there). But in summary, I need the percentage incremental calculation to be reset whenever one of these conditions exists, `1- I need this to work in a window between 0 and a maximum of 30 minutes.` `2- The value contained in the Price item of the current notification cannot be less than the value contained in the previous notification.` Any ideas/examples on how to resolve this in both perl and awk? Thanks